# Dockerfile "COPY" command confusion

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, dockerfile

I have 3 .NET6 projects in my local 'src' folder as below:

src/A

src/B

src/C

A: web api project, has many nuget dependencies

B: class lib, dependent of A

C: class lib, dependent of A

(Note: of course, project related files including .csproj are present in the local project folders)

My Dockerfile is in project folder A.
I am running the "docker build" command from 'src' folder (i.e. this is the build context) as below:

```
docker build -f A/Dockerfile -t myapiimage:v1 .
```

below section of code is from my Dockerfile, where i try to restore nuget dependencies:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./A/*.csproj A/
RUN dotnet restore A/A.csproj
```

this works fine and i understand that .csproj in the image is stored inside /src/A/A.csproj
**Am i right?**

**I want to know whether COPY preserves the source folder structure in the image being built or not?**

because after the below 3 lines:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.csproj ./
```

None of the line works:

```
RUN dotnet restore A/A.csproj
```

OR,

```
RUN dotnet restore A.csproj
```

OR,

```
RUN dotnet restore *A.csproj
```

OR,

```
RUN dotnet restore src/A/A.csproj
```

**So, where this .csproj files (of all 3 projects) are getting stored in the image?**

Answer (score 0):

Your line `COPY *.csproj ./` doesn't copy anything, because there are no .csproj files in your src directory on the host machine.

The way I usually do it is a bit clunky. First I do

```
COPY */*.csproj ./
```

which copies all the .csproj files into the workdir in the image. Then I do

```
RUN for file in $(ls *.csproj); do mkdir -p ${file%.*}/ && mv $file ${file%.*}/; done
```

which looks at all the .csproj files and creates a directory for them and moves them into that directory.

With that approach, your Dockerfile would look like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY */*.csproj ./  
RUN for file in $(ls *.csproj); do mkdir -p ${file%.*}/ && mv $file ${file%.*}/; done
RUN dotnet restore A/A.csproj
```

Comment: of course my local folders are having .csproj files, these are complete project folders having project related files including .csproj files. I have edited/added additional info in my question now. Though you gave some hints on how to copy these files and create a directory for them i the image, it is not the question i asked. If you see my code above (which works as indicated), i wanted to understand how the files reside in the image after the COPY operation.

Comment: My point is that they don't reside in the image, because your COPY statement doesn't copy anything. If you do something like `COPY . .` then everything from the build context gets copied and directory structures are preserved,

Comment: Okay, you cleared some of my doubts now. But why ```COPY . . ``` preserves the existing directory structures, but not ```COPY ./A/*.csproj A/```, I mean in this specific case the .csproj should get copied to ``` /src/A/ ``` directory. And then why my next statement ```RUN dotnet restore src/A/A.csproj``` doesn't find the .csproj file.

Comment: @Pankaj_Sen `COPY ./A/*.csproj A/` does work and puts the .csproj file into /src/A. What might be wrong is that you're missing a slash in the restore command. It should be `RUN dotnet restore /src/A/A.csproj`. Without the slash, it'll look for a file called /src/src/A/A.csproj, since the path is relative to the current directory, which is /src..

Comment: sorry I copied the wrong statement in my previous comment. I copied it from the statements what worked (as shown in my question), what i actually wanted to ask is if ```COPY . .``` preserves the existing directory structures, then why not ```COPY *.csproj ./```?  I mean then ```RUN dotnet restore src/A/A.csproj``` OR ```RUN dotnet restore /src/A/A.csproj``` OR ```RUN dotnet restore A/A.csproj``` should work.

Comment: I don't know the exact rules for when it does what, but when you copy a file to a directory, the host structure isn't preserved. When you copy a directory, structure is preserved. `COPY . .` copies a directory. `COPY *.csproj ./`  copies files.

Comment: Okay, a good info to try out ..thanks @Hans Kilian